# Synchronization: why startingBlock is ahead of currentBlock?

Tags: synchronization

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 908716,
  highestBlock: 928604,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 908891
}
```

It looks like synchronization started from block 908891, though the current block is 908716. How blocks 908717..908890 get synced then?

> startingBlock: QUANTITY - The block at which the import started (will only be reset, after the sync reached his head)
>
> currentBlock: QUANTITY - The current block, same as eth_blockNumber

Comment: Which client are you using ?

Comment: @SamuelDare I used Geth/v1.8.7 when saw it for the first time, then upgraded to Geth/v1.9.1, but still seeing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Geth Source code,

```
# StartingBlock is the block number at which synchronisation started.
    startingBlock: Long!
# CurrentBlock is the point at which synchronisation has presently reached.
    currentBlock: Long!
```

So the startingBlock is the point at which you originally started syncing i.e. when you first loaded your client , while the current block the progress you have made. When you started syncing your client,  highestBlock == startingBlock.

In other words when you start the sync

> currentBlock <= startingBlock<= highestBlock

However as the sync progresses, you would expect as the current block (the one on which you chain has synced ) passes the starting point .

> startingBlock  <= currentBlock <= highestBlock

Eventually,

> currentBlock === highestBlock

and the `eth.syncing` will return nill

## Reference:

- [Go Ethereum Source Code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/e8141e168560b8b1d2b50658c454adbfa905dacc/graphql/schema.go#L265)
- [Inferface.go - SyncProgress Struct](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/b04da9d48227b5d020a9668d06a5b92cb6746540/interfaces.go#L100)

Comment: Doesn't it mean that startingBlock <= currentBlock <= highestBlock?

Comment: It’s the same thing but I guess my answer is way too verbose will update

Comment: But then in my case, why startingBlock > currentBlock ?

Comment: sorry i must be totally confusing you..  will make one more attempt

Comment: Aah, got it now.. I assumed that the logic should be "startingBlock = currentBlock on startup", but it makes sense if it's actually "startingBlock = highestBlock on startup".

Comment: Precisely will update the answer to show that nuance . We go there eventually!